# Compiling the Linux kernel required disk space

Tags: kernel, compiling

I'm new to Linux kernel development and had a question concerning the disk space required to build the kernel.

I just compiled Linux stable kernel version 5.7.7 using the olddefconfig Make recipe and wound up with 22G total space used and 14G for the drivers folder alone.

Is this a typical size for a kernel build? Or did I do something that caused a lot of additional files to be built?

I'm very new to this and thought that using olddefconfig sounded like it would create a configuration for the build that would match the current system.

I was able to boot to the new kernel without issues, but this seems like a lot of space to use based on what I've read so far.

The current system is just a minimal install of Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2 in a VirtualBox VM.

Comment: Seems plausible if the build was with debug information.